# Azure P2S VPN with Azure AD Authentication Client for Server 2019

Tags: azure, vpn, windows-server-2019

Anyone was successful configuring a VPN client on Server 2019 build 1809 for Azure VPN Gateway using OpenVPN and Azure Active Directory authentication?

Windows Admin Center allows to add an Azure Network Adaptor, but there is only an option for certificate authentication when I select my existing VNet.

Also, Azure VPN Client is not available since there is no MS Store in Server 2019.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently, the Windows server 2019 is not available for Azure AD authentication and Azure AD authentication is supported only for OpenVPN protocol connections. Read [Configure a VPN client for P2S OpenVPN protocol connections: Azure AD authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-client) and [this step-by-step guide](https://medium.com/@syerge/azure-point-to-site-p2s-connection-with-azure-ad-authentication-4584a90bad88).

The table below shows the client operating systems and the authentication options that are available to them. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/work-remotely-support
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I somehow missed this table. Looking forward for support for Server 2019 then.